# iPhone SDK - check iPod playlist to see whether there is a next track to skip to

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipod, mpmusicplayercontroller

Is there a way to inspect the current playlist from MPMusicPlayerController to see whether there is another track to play in the queue?

It's possible to detect this after as skipToNextItem will stop playback and change playbackState, but I want to find out before, so I can disable the skip track function if there are no more tracks to skip on to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a way to do this since `MPMusicPlayerController` offers no access to its playlist whatsoever. I hope Apple adds this functionality in a future SDK release. You should file a feature request with them.

Answer (score -3):

Oh yes you can, with [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery]. At least you can find out which playlist that is playing and you can start to play a song title in a playlist. I don't know how to continue to play the next item in the playlist, though.